# could not use tqdm_notebook in notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

When I use the `tqdm_notebook` in iteration:

`from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm`

It only shows:

```
HBox(children=(IntProgress(value=1, bar_style='info', max=1), HTML(value='')))
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 11):

Probably you don't have ipywidgets installed.

For Jupyter Notebook you can check with 
`$ jupyter nbextension list`

For Jupyter Lab you can check with
`$ jupyter labextension list`

Installing ipywidgets is described [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_install.html)

Comment: The install page isn't super clear.  For jupyter lab, run `jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager`

Answer (score 3):

For use in JupyterLab:

1. install ipywidgets package:

   **With pip**

   > pip install ipywidgets

   > jupyter nbextension enable --py widgetsnbextension

   **With conda**

   > conda install -c conda-forge ipywidgets

   (Installing ipywidgets with conda will also enable the extension for you.)
2. Then run the following command to install the Jupyter widgets extension for FigureWidget support (note that this will require **nodeJs** to be installed in your system):

> jupyter labextension install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager

Comment: Windows users: Please note that you need to restart Windows after installing Node.js.